# Vue 3 dynamically loaded component hooks not called

Tags: vue.js, import, async-await

I have this (shorten for the question) single file component (vue 3.2.31):

```
<template lang="pug">
.test Hello world!
</template>
<style lang="sass" scoped>
.test
  font-weight: bold
</style>
<script setup lang="ts">

onMounted(() => {
  console.log('Mounted');
});

</script>
```

It is bundled via [vitejs](https://vitejs.dev/), exported as (let's say) `NamedExport` and served on demand as a **base64 encoded string** to be imported client-side.

```
const component = await defineAsyncComponent(async () => {

  // A module that exports multiple components.
  const module = await import(base64StringSentFromTheServer);

  // Choose one.
  return module['NamedExport']);

})
```

then, the result is bound to:

```
<component :is="component" />
```

It **works well**, except two things, one of these is that hooks are not called (`onMounted` in this case), the other being that styles importer is not called either.

Is it an expected behavior, or do I miss something? Is it the `<script setup>` way of writing the component that is responsible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I had **two instances of Vue running** (one bundled with my package, with rollup, and one imported in the script itself), and for an unknown reason, none of the two was calling hooks.

By removing one of the instances (actually, passing *vue* as external in rollup build configuration) it now works well.